# Output to devices in Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, arm, device

I was wondering how, exactly, one is able to read and write directly to and from I/O devices using assembly or C with no system libraries. I know, for instance, that you can render to text-based VGA in x86 real mode by writing character data to 0xB8000. But how do you gain access to other devices, on other CPU architectures? Are they all memory-mapped from the start, or are there tricks to get them to be when you need them?

Specifically, I would like to know, in C or ARM asm, how would I read/write to vga in text mode, a usb port, and a ps/2 port. I don't need to know about the standard communication protocols, I can figure that out on my own. I would just like to know how to identify and communicate with ports and other devices.

For the compiler and assembler, I am using a cross-compiled GNU toolchain running on x86_64 as the host architecture. I don't have any libraries or an operating system on the target machine, so I am really just making flat binaries and writing them to the boot sector of an sd card. The hardware is a raspberry pi model b.

Comment: I guess you are basically asking how does an OS accomplish those things. You can look at [`ARM Linux`](http://www.arm.linux.org.uk/) to see how it's done there.

Comment: I've tried, but deciphering kernel code is difficult to say the least

Comment: Posting the small parts of the code you don't understand or can't follow and asking about it would probably be a better way for you to get to the answers you want.

Comment: @dwelch This is a bare-metal question, I do believe that I even said that in the OP. And I was wondering specifically HOW you would talk to a peripheral. The cited example with vga, as Ben Brammer pointed out, is only viable in x86 real mode, whereas I'm programming for ARM, where I don't even know how to talk to the video card.

Comment: @dwelch So now we come back to my original question: how do I map devices to memory, and how do I "indirectly" talk to usb?

Comment: ethernet, usb, uart/serial are not always this way but good examples where you talk to the ethernet controller or usb controller, etc, that is what is in your processors address space.  you do whatever that ethernet controller wants to compose the packet then you ask the ethernet controller to send the packet.  that is like telling the truckdriver where you want them to drive the truck.  independent of that you fill the truck with the payload, the data that the other side needs.

Comment: usb you may have to deal with the truckdriver and certainly the payload, the payload format is specific to the class of usb device and then within that it might be specific to the brand/model/version of that peripheral.  sometimes you dont have to do that, sometimes there is hardware that does much of the work for you (esp with microcontrollers).

Comment: pci/pcie, once setup and configured, you often have a chunk of memory space in the processors address space that when you talk to those addresses get turned into pcie addresses in the pci address space then peripherals on pcie busses look for their address in pci address space, and if you are talking to them they answer.  again truckdriver stuff, then the specific addresses within that peripherals address space could be pixel memory or control registers, and the payload, the data, is specific to that peripheral and what component of that peripheral.

Comment: x86 because of bashing in the past likes to try to give the illusion of a flat memory space and carve a chunk of the address space for pcie and the processor and pcie address space use the same physical addresses (at least up to the common number of address bits).  So you might see an address of 0xE0000000 both in x86 and pcie address space, but they are two address spaces.  and the window for x86 pcie is pretty small 1 or 2 gig for everything, so you still have to do some sort of page scheme to talk to everything (well it depends on the peripheral).

Comment: x86 pci enumeration happens in the bios, by the time the OS has started pcie is configured (same goes for dram).  other non-x86 worlds do not have these features/limitations (they are both good and bad features).  and it is dependent on that environment/systems design as to whether the processor and pci address spaces try to match each other or if there is a more obvious translation.  you have to dig into the docs and or linux or bsd drivers (open source) to figure out how a particular system does something

Comment: the truckdriver and the payload idea is like fopen/close/read/write, dealing with the truckdriver means opening the file and using the fread/fwrite api function calls.  independent of that the payload is the actual data you wish to read or write the file system.  the amount of code behind fopen/read/write/close can be and is quite large, again disks are not a trivial thing you just jump into first thing.  Start with serial ports (uarts) and other relatively simpler interfaces.

Comment: blinking an led is usually the best first thing on a new system even if you have decades of experience.and it can take you hours to get that to work depending on the system and quality of the documentation. next perhaps, not always, turning on or blinking the led is an I/O output, you could setup another pin for input, and if the input is high then turn the led on input off turn the led off and put a switch or touch a wire from the pin to vcc or ground, basic gpio. then move to uarts then more other stuff,video, ethernet, usb,etc being things you do later,using the led and uart for debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking this level of question, vga text mode is a long long way away from the first thing you should be trying.  Although that depends on your platform of course.  If this is a raspberry pi, then I would still start with blinking leds and then the uart, then do video if you so desire, video on the raspberry pi is quite trivial.   Text mode, there isnt, you have to draw the pixels, but with a little experience with raster based fonts (do this on your x86 machine make bitmaps or print strings of xxes and 00s or something) you can easily come up with a font set and then for each character just draw the pixels.

The language has little to do with it, C or asm work fine, most folks do C and asm only when needed, that is the recommendation I would give as well.

I have many bare metal examples (github.com/dwelch67), one of which for the gba does a little bit of font stuff with an 8x8 font, which you can steal from me I dont care.  I have yet to actually do the raspberry pi video stuff, but there are soo many examples, you go through one gyration to get a pointer in the arm address space (And set the video mode, etc) and then it is just a matter of writing pixel data to that memory range and the gpu echos it to the video card.

the beaglebone black or one of the allwinner cards (pcduino, apc.io) (I would avoid those due to lack of documentation) could be used, they have different video interfaces than the raspberry pi, so more work is involved.  I have yet to figure out the beaglebone black for bare metal, and have some allwinner info but have not done any real bare metal there.  So dont buy unless you know someone else has done it.  Actually the early ipods, classi gen 1 - at least 5, the ipod nano gen 1, are not hard to do video with if video is really what you are after.  The gameboy advance is pretty easy and there are gazillions of examples and visualboyadvance is a good simulator so you dont really need hardware you can start writing arm code to draw pixels right now.

the hawkboard and pandaboard are also something you might want to look at I think both have video, I have a couple of hawkboards and bare metal is easy, dont have a pandaboard.  I have also used a open-rd board, dont remember what it has on it...

If you want a pc like experience with pcie cards that is a lot more work you have to setup the root complex, reset and train the endpoints, configure them, then you can talk to them and depending on the video chip/board determines how much work is involved in even the simplest video task.  (if the video card uses system memory then you have to bring that up, if it is ddr then pcie is very trivial compared to bringing up ddr).

start with the game boy advance simulator.

Comment: This is everything I could have asked for and more! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, what you say about VGA is only partly true; in *real* mode, that is correct.  History lesson: the reason that DOS only provided 640K of memory was to reserve the remaining addressable memory for device drivers.  This is the same reason that the Linux kernel is compressed; until the processor is switched into protected mode, in which case, every process has it's own virtual memory space.  Device drivers (basically) work by, at some level, translating calls to the driver to actual getting and putting of data to the hardware buffer of the device.

tl;dr.  What you're asking is specific to the hardware and OS you're writing to.  Sorry I can't be more specific.

Comment: Sorry about the inaccuracy in the OP, I meant that I could write to vga on x86 cpus in real mode with memory mapped I/O. However, ARM has neither real mode nor protected mode, and I have no OS. Given these things, there surely must be a way to at the very least find out what hardware is available. I mean, the linux kernel does it.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by a) choosing an assembly architecture e.g. MIPS or likewise. If you have not programmed assembly before I suggest you choose MIPS since it is easier than x86 and then b) looking at how to transfer data with the serial port to begin with since this illustrates memory-mapped i/o that is used. FPGA is a nice way to learn this if you are training.

To write to hardware, you do write to certain memory addresses using memory-mapped i/o. I could not find any documentation how ARm does it, but in Nios 2 assembly, which is a RISC, writing to hardware is for example: writing the value 0x17 to address 0x810 will light LEDs LEDR4, LEDR2, LEDR1, and LEDR0 and the serial port also has a memory address that you can write transmit data to.

Comment: I've already done (a), and I'm asking here for the answer to (b).

Comment: @jepugs Good, I'll try to expand on (b) with an updated answer a.s.a.p. I see you tagged the question ARM so you want to know about RISC architecture but I don't know how similar ARM and MIPS are, I only know MIPS and not x86 or ARM.